# Mysql listing records based on time

Tags: mysql

I have used the following query to get all the records which matches the given time in WHERE clause. But I am getting different results. If you look into tat picture you can see the 2 records have minutes <> 30 but still it is listed as the query result. However if i change the hour they are not listed. What might be the problem ?

`SELECT * FROM pos_takeaways WHERE STR_TO_DATE(time,'%d/%m/%y %H:%U:%S') = STR_TO_DATE('20/6/2011 22:30:00','%d/%m/%Y %H:%U:%S')`

Output:
[image]

Comment: How is the time stored in your database??

Comment: its normal string varchar format.. and the format is as shown in the time field above..

Comment: If it is varchar, then you could just do it like string comparison right, than converting them to date and then checking

Comment: Shouldn't your format string be `%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S` instead of `%d/%m/%y %H:%U:%S`?

Comment: if i use %M i am getting incorrect format error!!

Comment: @Balanivash: the reason for formatting is because if i change it to time format i can handle different type of date time formats. Its hard for me to maintain the format of datetime all the time. So using STR_TO_DATE() help me handle tat issue.

Comment: Just want to clarify something, using DATETIME is better right, so why did you go for storing the date as varchar??

Comment: @Balanivash: I am not formatting the date in proper format while i input it to the database. DATETIME needs to be strictly formatted and for me to display the results in different field is a pain if i store it in DATETIME format. I will use DATETIME only when comparing and when i output the result i need it in other formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 2 issues:

1. your query should use "<=" rather than "=".
2. instead of %U, use %i in the argument to STR_TO_DATE (%U is for the week number)

   SELECT * 
   FROM pos_takeaways 
   WHERE STR_TO_DATE(time,'%d/%m/%y %H:%i:%S') <= STR_TO_DATE('20/6/2011 22:30:00','%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S');

Hope this helps.

Comment: why to use <= if i need to get records on == basis ?? but your `2` works for me. thanks.. i want to know the reason for `1` before i accept this answer..

Comment: @Deepak: surely I agree that you should not use <= if your requirement is =. But from your resultset example above, I thought that perhaps you might need to show records that are less than 22:30:00 and so I suggested doing a <=. Please ignore that suggestion if it isn't what you need :-)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that there is some problem with `STR_TO_DATE` function in MySQL, check `http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56271`. So, if you are using a old version of MySQL (6 months old), then this might be the cause, and you should consider upgrading your MySQL. If this is not a problem, try using `BETWEEN AND` using the same value in both the fields.
[Operator Between](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between). Don't forget to check their warning regarding using it for `DATE` comparison

Comment: well thanks for your help.. i got it working by the solution above.. +1 to ur replies..